# Can't access Gmail. Suspicious security question

Tags: gmail

Can't access Gmail account adamsfreeman@gmail.com. When security question appears, it's in a different language. Looks to be some Asian language. Not sure what to do.

Comment: Google doesn't ask any "security questions". Also: Enable 2FA.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the language. See below.

[image: .]

Hope this help.